# cassandra installing on centOS 6 using yum install dsc20 says following and not installed

Tags: cassandra, yum, centos6

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  * base: ftp.osuosl.org  * extras: centosy3.centos.org  * rpmforge: repoforge.mirror.constant.com  * updates: centosu5.centos.org datastax                                                                                                                                        |  951 B     00:00 Setting up Install Process No package dsc20 available.

Comment: stored in repo at /etc/yum.repos.d/datastax.repo following  [datastax] 
name = DataStax Repo for Apache Cassandra
baseurl = http://rpm.datastax.com/community
enabled = 1
gpgcheck = 0

Comment: I think this question would better fit other stackexchange platforms like superuser or unix?

Answer (score 0):

As Orajinder pointed out you need to do the following:

Add the repo to your list of supported repositories:

```
sudo vim /etc/yum.repos.d/datastax.repo

[datastax]
name= DataStax Repo for Apache Cassandra
baseurl=http://rpm.datastax.com/community
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Then install

```
sudo yum install dsc20
```

Comment: It should be noted that for other datastax products you actually require user authentication to pull down the versions and you would update the baseurl there to reflect this.